# which mysql 32 / 64 bit

Tags: mysql

How good it'd be to have 64 bit MySQL on 64 bit Linux ofcouse?
Presently I have 32bit Mysql / OS but 64bit hardware.
Shall I consider upgrade? What advantages do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the main advantage of 64bit software - you will be able to address more RAM

Answer (score 0):

> What advantages do I have?

Potentially bigger in-memory caches.  And big caches can really help database performance ... in some cases.  However, I've also noticed evidence that suggests that there is a limit to which application caches help, and that in some situations a OS level file caches work better at reducing disc IO delays.

For some hints on how 64bit MySQL (with appropriate tuning) might help, read [How MySQL Uses Memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-use.html) from the MySQL manual.

Comment: Answers to questions like that will be highly application specific.